# How to Trade Between Pokemon Fire Red and Leaf Green emulator on my Macbook pro?

Tags: emulation, pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

I would like to trade pokemon for evolution between fire red and leaf green emulators for trades. However, I cannot seem to get an emulator that works on my Macbook Mojave to load 2 games at once.

The save files I am using are .sav

I have tried VBA, but had no luck as the instances keep not connecting.

Please could someone help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution on how to trade pokemon.

#### Prerequisites:

BACK UP YOUR SAVE FILES FIRST!

I have lost a few saves and sometimes the namespacing can change on a filename, so I would advise you save your files and find out where your saves are stored too so if you need to re name them afterwards, you can do.

See this on how to get your IP address: https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/h...

Here are the key steps in the video:

#### Before trading

1. Download VBA - M from GitHub: https://github.com/visualboyadvance-m...
   Install the right version for your system, I have installed the 64 bit.
2. Copy VBA - M to Applications folder
3. Copy VBA - M in the Applications folder so that you have 2 VBAs, in there as shown in the video.
4. Make sure that the games actively run in the background first before any trading, so that you can have both Fire Red and Leaf Green active at not frozen if not selected.
5. Always use a keyboard to control the VBA and not a Bluetooth controller - if you use a Bluetooth controller, it also controls the game in the background which is not what you want, so have the keyboard set up first.

#### Starting the trade

6. Open both VBAs up, do not load the game, just open them
7. Go to link, select link type as cable (not wireless)
8. Start network link, set one as server with your IP address, and the other VBA as client.
9. They should connect
10. load the games
11. Complete the trade
12. Save the game afterward
13. Check your saves and it should all be there

I have also shown how to achieve this in a YouTube video -

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot trade Pokemon on PC emulators.

The best way to get around this for future playthroughs is to download  the Universal Pokemon Randomizer application. This application lets you change the game in dozens of ways including my favorite one which is called "Change Impossible Evos" as seen below[image]

This option makes it so pokemon that need special evoloutions will not need to be traded to evolve. Instead evolving at a high level. For example Haunter will evolve at level 37+ to Gengar.

You can find the application site and download [HERE](https://pokehacks.dabomstew.com/randomizer/).

If you want to read more on what the change does in emulators you can visit [THIS](https://pokehacks.dabomstew.com/randomizer/changedevos.php) link

Lastly here is a step by step guide to setting up the Randomizer as it is can be a pain to get started.

1. If you've already started playing, make sure you get your save file out and back it up. If you haven't started a game yet, just download the ROM you're going to 
        use.
2. Open your Pokemon ROM in the application. Select the option called "Change Impossible Evolutions." DON'T SELECT ANY OTHER OPTION unless you want to make other tweaks to your game.
3. Click the "Randomize (Save)" button on the right. Again, this won't randomize your ROM unless you selected other options beyond "Change Impossible Evos"—it's just saving the changes you made.
4. Load the new ROM file into your emulator. If you have a save file from before, make sure it gets into the new ROM's folder in the appropriate place.
5. Start the game and play as normal.

Hope this helps.